# Is System.nanoTime(); or System.currentTimeMillis(); better for a game

Tags: java, milliseconds, nanotime

In a game loop everyone uses `System.nanoTime()` but for something like animations, the speed of something, etc some people use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and some use `System.nanoTime()`. Which one should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using whichever is appropriate to your needs.

The two examples you gave are fundamentally different:

- For animations, you simply need to meet the demands of the screen refresh rate which will be less that 100 times per second.  For that a millisecond clock is fine.  (Beyond 50 or so refreshes a second, a typical human can't tell the difference.)
- For game loops, you could make an argument that "fairness" means you should make the clocks as accurate as possible.  (And I'm sure some game players would make that argument.)  If you accept that argument, then nanosecond clocks are more appropriate.

Nobody is likely to actually<sup>1</sup> tell the difference between using millisecond or nanosecond clocks in games and other applications where the primary goal is smooth human-computer interaction.

In short: there is no "right" way.

---

<sup>1 - They may *think* that they can tell, but it wouldn't stand up to rigorous scientific testing.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`currentTimeMillis()` is effectively a wall clock. It's very cheap to call but usually (this might depend on the JVM implementation and the hardware) doesn't provide millisecond granularity and is susceptible to drift e.g. due to CPU core voltage.

`nanoTime()` is a precise clock that should be used for measuring elapsed time. It will be more expensive to call but as long as you are not doing this hundred times per second it shouldn't matter in the big picture.

Use the one that suits your purpose. You can read more about it in [Inside the Hotspot VM: Clocks, Timers and Scheduling Events - Part I - Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308031939/https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) which sums it all up with:

> If you are interested in measuring absolute time then always use System.currentTimeMillis(). Be aware that its resolution may be quite coarse (though this is rarely an issue for absolute times.)
>
> If you are interested in measuring/calculating elapsed time, then always use System.nanoTime(). On most systems it will give a resolution on the order of microseconds. Be aware though, this call can also take microseconds to execute on some platforms.